# maven package jar + specific dependency

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have an maven project which I want to package it as a jar with a few dependencies (not all).

For that, I am trying to use the maven assembly plugin, like the following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/dependency.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

dependency.xml

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">

    <id>dependency</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <includes>
                <include>any_dependency</include>
            </includes>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

However, with this, it create two jars: jar_project and jar_project_dependency.
I really want to make both jars into only one.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To create a so called jar-with-dependencies there is a predifined descriptor which can be used. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html but for more flexibility you could use maven-shade-plugin instead...

Comment: I strongly recommend not to create a jar-with-dependencies which will be used in other projects to consumes... that will prevent overwrites etc. Only usuable for an executable jar...

Comment: Most probably, maven-shade-plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html is what you are looking for.